# why does scanf() not work when followed by a loop?

Tags: c, string, loops, scanf

When I enter a string in the code below, the program doesn't move on. It just allows me to keep typing and pressing enter with no effect. Why does this happen and how can I fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

char str[20];
int aaa = 0;
int exit;

printf("Enter anything: ");
scanf("%s", str);

while(aaa == 0) {
  if(str[3] == 'a') {
    aaa++; } 
  else {
    scanf("%d", &exit);
    if(exit == 3) {
      aaa++; } } }

printf("%s\n", str);

}
```

Log:

```
Enter anything: 2/3/4444
Now
it
just
lets
me
keep
on
typing
```

Edit: I solved it and I’m a bit embarrassed at how simple it was. I know people have been trying to explain this to me but in my own words this is what was happening: as the condition to enter the while loop was being met the program would enter the while loop. However, unless the input entered for the scanf satisfied one of the conditions in the loop, the program had no way of leaving the loop and therefore, it would get stuck. Basically I was simply missing an else statement which solved this problem.

Comment: Please show the exact input that you have entered. In particular did you enter anything that would trigger either of the exit conditions?

Comment: At first I entered a date 4/2/1985 for example as I was using this to help with a program dealing with dates. However, the same problem occurred no matter what input I entered.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67116522/edit) your question to update it with the **exact and complete** input and output. That is, run your program then paste in the log. It's still not clear whether you entered any of the exit condition - an inital string with `a` as the fourth character or a `3` after that.

Comment: This exits for me if I type "aaaa<enter>" as the first entry or "3<enter>" as the second entry. I don't see why you think entering "4/2/1985<enter>" would cause it to exit.

Comment: @Jampat-08 Can you edit your question to show the precise sequence of steps you took, what results you expected, and what results you got? The code does what I expect it to do. It's not quite clear what you expected it to do. When you entered "4/2/1985", did you enter anything before that? Because this code only accepts a string as its very first input.

Comment: I understand that it exits when str[3] is a but I want it to run the else statement when str[3] isn't a and currently it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Jampat-08, in your example, none of those values that you've entered will trigger either of your exit conditions.  Do you understand how your own code is working?

Comment: @Jampat-08 The code in the `else` can only read an integer. There's no integer in your example input. After the string, you *must* enter an integer because that's the only thing your program can accept after it has read in a string.

Comment: This will go into an infinite loop if you enter anythin other than a number after the first string.  You should be checking the return value of scanf

Comment: Also note that using just `main()` is valid in C90, but there have been three versions of the standard since then (C99, C11, C18) and it was not valid in any of those.  Use `int main(void) { … }` or `int main(int argc, char **argv) { … }`.  And not putting `return 0;` at the end of `main()` in a C90 program leads to undefined behaviour — you can only omit it if you're working with C99 or later.

Comment: Please use a more orthodox indentation style for C.
I strongly recommend either Allmann (which is what I use, more or less)
or some version of 1TBS (which is used by many other people).  See
Wikipedia on [Indentation
Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for information
about the variants.

The Pico style, especially with multiple `}` markers on a single line, is anathema in C.

Multiple close braces on a single line is a no-no;
multiple consecutive close braces at the same indent level is another.

Comment: Proper indentation would make it easier for you to understand what the code does. You can even use sites like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm to auto-indent the code for you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I expect it to take the input from scanf() and then carry on to the while loop regardless of what I enter into the scanf(). I'm relatively new to C so if this isn't how this should be done could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is carrying on into the loop. It is the second scanf that is reading your 2nd - nth lines. What do you expect the second scanf to be doing?

Comment: @EdmCoff I expected the second scanf to take a separate input altogether. How would I acheive this? Would I need to use fgets instead of scanf?

Comment: It does take a separate input, but you're trying to read it into an int. If you want to read arbitrary strings, you should change the second scanf to use "%s" into another character array (like the first scanf). Possible you should be using fgets, but I still don't understand what you want the program to do, so I don't know if that's necessary.

Comment: Or, to hopefully be more clear: In your example, the first `scanf` reads "2/3/4444" into `str`. Then it enters the loop. The second `scanf` tries to read an integer and finds the text "Now" so it doesn't put anything in `exit`. Each iteration, it keeps reading "Now" looking for an integer and never finds one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a string whose fourth character is not an `a`, your program reads an integer. It will never attempt to read anything but an integer after that first read. So you *must* *not* enter anything but an integer after the first string.

If you want your program to handle a non-integer after the string, you need to add code to do that. You currently have none.